# jsp translate xml to html using xsl

Tags: xml, html, jsp, taglib

I have a web application and I want to transform a xml to html using my custom xsl in jsp.

When I test the xml and xsl using altovaXMLSPY, it works.

But in the jsp, there is something wrong.

The directory looks like this:

```
--root
   my.jsp
  --WEB-INF
    taglibs-xsl.tld
    --classes
      my.xml
      my.xsl
```

The jsp is look like this one:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"  pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<%@taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/xsl-1.0" prefix="xsl"%>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

    <%@ page%>

    <title>my jsp</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            <xsl:apply nameXml="WEB-INF/classes/my.xml" xsl="WEB-INF/classes/my.xsl" /> 
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And the error is:

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Missing bean 'WEB-INF/classes/my.xml'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure but I guess the xsl:apply does a request to get the XML,

requests can not access the WEB-INF directory,

maybe move your xml/xsl files outside of the WEB-INF dir to see if that helps?

also I think nameXml refers to a session variable, use xml="/my.xml" instead